# Не работает удаления в бинарном файле

Tags: c++, c

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include "Heade1r.h"
using namespace std;
void choose1_del() {
    ifstream f1;
    int n;
    float t, m;
    cout << "Введите число за которое удаления должно быть больше \n";
    cin >> m;
    f1.read((char*)&n, sizeof(n));
    int i = 0;
    while (i < n) {
        f1.read((char*)&t, sizeof(t));
        i++;
            if (t > m) {
                delet(i + 1);
                i = 0;
                f1.close();
                f1.open("file.txt", ios::binary);
                f1.read((char*)&n, sizeof(n));
            }
    }
}
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include "Heade1r.h"
using namespace std;
void choose2_del() {
    ifstream f1;
    int n;
    float t, m;
    cout << "Введите число за которое удаления должно быть меньше\n";
    cin >> m;
    f1.read((char*)&n, sizeof(n));
    int i = 0;
    while (i < n) {
        f1.read((char*)&t, sizeof(t));
        i++;
        if (t < m) {
            delet(i - 1);
            i = 0;
            f1.close();
            f1.open("file.txt", ios::binary);
            f1.read((char*)&n, sizeof(n));
        }
    }
}
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include "Heade1r.h"
using namespace std;
void choose3_del() {
    ifstream f1;
    int n;
    float t, m;
    cout << "Введите число за которое удаления должно быть равно\n";
    cin >> m;
    f1.read((char*)&n, sizeof(n));
    int i = 0;
    while (i < n) {
        f1.read((char*)&t, sizeof(t));
        i++;
        if (t == m) {
            delet(i = 1);
            i = 0;
            f1.close();
            f1.open("file.txt", ios::binary);
            f1.read((char*)&n, sizeof(n));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Это у вас один файл такой кишкой?... Как говорится, вангую: в таком огромном коде, без указания, что конкретно и где не работает, никто ковыряться не станет...

Comment: программно ничего не работает, когда выводит меню нажимаю на любую цифру в меню выводит риндомни числа и все

Comment: 1) Какую вам ошибку выдает при компиляции? 2) Я уверен половина кода, которого вы выложили не нужен. 3) Если же вы считаете, что весь код важен для решения проблемы, то будьте добры не в блок засовывать код всех файлов,  а разбить на несколько блоков и подписать блоки соответствующими названиями файлов. 4) Уж постарайтесь комментарии хоть какие-то оставлять в коде. Иначе все мимо будут проходить ваш вопрос.

Отредактируйте пожалуйста свой вопрос

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> f1.read((char*)&n, sizeof(n));
> ```

Ну и откуда ты это читаешь? Файл же не открывался.